# Installing canvas on ubuntu

Tags: canvas, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I am installing canvas on ubuntu 16.04 LTS for installing npm package qr-js.

I performed these steps - 
 1. sudo apt-get update 
 2. sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++
3. sudo npm install canvas

and the result is-

```
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! canvas@1.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.4.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
```

my nodejs version is v4.2.6 & npm is v3.5.2

can any body help me..?

Answer (score 0):

I think the canvas installation faces issues wit the new kernel present in v16.04 of Ubuntu.  Try using v14.04.  Hope this helped.

I.M.

Answer (score 0):

I could relatively solve the problem, I had the same problem, well thats my case I was attempted to install canvas locally and it wasn't possible I don't know why, however was possible install globally so the idea was change the path where I call the "canvas" I was attempted run some example I could find here.
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas .
The only change I did was change <> by var Canvas = require('canvas') and the way how construct an object var canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(200, 200) by I hope it can find someone! .